# $f(x)$ irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ of prime degree ; then Galois group of $f$ is solvable iff $L=\mathbb Q(a,b)$ for any two roots $a,b$ of $f$?

Tags: reference-request, galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field, solvable-groups

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb Q[x]$ be irreducible polynomial of prime degree , $L$ be its splitting field , then how to show that $f(x)$ is solvable by radicals over $\mathbb Q$ iff $L=\mathbb Q(a,b)$ for any two roots $a,b$ of $f(x)$ ? i.e. how to show that $Gal(L/\mathbb Q)$ is solvable iff $L=\mathbb Q(a,b)$ for any two roots $a,b$ of $f(x)$ ?

EDIT : Any reference of book or article giving a full demonstration of the result is also highly appreciated

Comment: This one is straight from Galois paper (*Memoir on the Conditions for Solvability of Equations by Radicals*) where he shows that an irreducible polynomial of prime degree with rational coefficients is solvable by radicals if and only if all the roots of the equation can be expressed as rational functions of two roots.

Comment: The assertion is definitely false for a generic quartic.

Comment: @MooS: the degree of polynomial should be a prime $p$ and there will be $p(p - 1)$ elements in the Galois group (at least this is what Galois says in his memoir).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yes, but this is not mentioned in the question itself, so the assertion in the question is false. The prime degree case is handled in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24081/solvable-transitive-groups-of-prime-degree...

Comment: @MooS , ParamanandaSingh : Sorry , I did want to mean prime degree

Comment: @ParamanandSingh : Could you please elaborate the argument as an answer ?

Comment: I am myself studying these topics and do not find myself confident enough to post an answer here. I was aware of the memoir of Galois as presented in H. M. Edwards' *Galois Theory* hence I quoted the reference. But I am sure you will get a good answer here from many expert people.

Comment: I saw the demonstration in several books on Galois theory. Simply go to your local library and find the right book. It is also possible to understand the original demonstration of Galois, despite this is not evident (I did it when I was younger, but I do not recall the argument). In fact, if you write down here the demonstration of Galois and pin point the step that is confusing you, I may be able to help you.

Comment: @MikeTeX : Can you please give a reference of some book(s) then ?

Comment: No, but I saw this proof explained in one or two book in "theory of equations".

Comment: It goes roughly like this. 
Let $G$ be the Galois group $G(L/\mathbb{Q})$ and the subfield $K=\mathbb{Q}(a,b)$ of the splitting field $L$. Then $K$ is the fixed field of the subgroup $H=\{g\in G\mid g(a)=a,g(b)=b\}$ of $G$. Suppose $G$ is soluble. It's transitive too since $f$ is irreducible. Since $L/K$ is Galois, then $H$ inherites the transitivity and solubility. But the only automorphism of a transitive and soluble group  that fixes two elements is the identity because such a group is conjugated to the affine linear group. Hence $H=(1)$, in other words, $L=K$.

Comment: Conversely, if $K=L$,we know that $|G|=[K:\mathbb{Q}]$ is divisible by $p$ (irreducible) and by $p-1$ (the degree of the second root), so by $p(p-1)$, so $|G|\leq p(p-1)$. The number of $p$-Sylow is $1\mod p$, and must be smaller than $p(p-1)$, so $G$ has only one $p$-Sylow so the $p$-Sylow is normal in $G$ If the symmetric group $S_p$, this means that $G$ contains a $p$-cycle, which generates a normal subgroup of $G$, thus is a subgroup of a solvable group, the affine linear group.

Comment: http://library.lol/main/51D4B5102D1D6C18A4225563ADE60346;     Pg 262 of this book has a proof ....hope you find this helpful